# Help with displaying php time/date function using javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I want to remove the meta date from being displayed by Google's search. I came across this code usually found in single.php

```
<?php the_time(‘M j, Y’);?>
```

Needs to be re-written as:

```
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”> document.write(‘<?php the_time(‘j’) ?>’); </script> <?php the_time(‘M Y’) ?>
```

However my single.php uses this format

```
<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>
```

How can I use javascript for the above code?

Comment: the_time? never seen this, is that ur own function or ur framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language=”javascript” type=”text/javascript”> document.write(‘<?php the_time(get_option("date_format")); ?>’);</script>
```

That will conceal the entire date, not just the day-of-the-month.  (Is that what you want?)

Comment: This is the error it gives: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Comment: @Trott: you forgot to `echo` the `the_time` funciton... :)

Comment: So it would be in this format then? document.write('<?php echo 'the_time(get_option("date_format");'?>')

Comment: @Vaibhav: I didn't have balanced parentheses.  I just edited it to fix it.  Try it now.

Comment: @Vaibhav: No need to `echo` and in fact that would probably not work.  It's clear from the code that OP posts in the question that `the_time()` does the echoing itself.  It likely returns true or false, so adding an `echo` would probably not have the result OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

Although one liner would work, code written up like this leads to code clutterage.
You code should be read and easy to follow, like a book.

```
<?php 
// the date() object should be used for this, and the following would normally by 
// shoved in a function. 

$date['j'] = the_time('j',get_option('date_format'));
$date['M'] = the_time('M', get_option('date_format'));
$date['Y'] = the_time('Y', get_option('date_format'));
// Build the date string the way want it
$date['full'] = "Today, the " .  $date['j'] . "of " . $date['M'] . ", " . $date['Y'];
?>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">document.write('<?php echo date["full"]; ?>');</script>
```